# Table Bring all comments for one article using yajra/laravel-datatables

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

when try to get all comment for one Article by `Article::first()`  but `first()` 
Bring just the first article 
i try use `find()` like

```
$comments = Article::find()-> commentsArticle()->with('articles');
return Datatables::of($comments)
```

i get error so how i can Pass a value to view all comments for one article
or
my be there is way without using `find()`

Article model

```
class Article extends Model{

 public $table = 'articles';

 public function commentsArticle() {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
     }

 }
```

controller

```
enter code here

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;

use App\Article;
use App\Comment;


class CommentController extends Controller{


   public function commentsForOne Article()
  {
    $comments = Article::all()->commentsArticle->with('articles');

            return Datatables::of($comments)->make(true);
  }

}
```

last error i get

```
ErrorException (E_DEPRECATED)
Non-static method Yajra\Datatables\Datatables::collection() should       
not be called statically
```

I hope find any idea or example like that will help me to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the first articles with its comments.

```
public function commentsForOneArticle($id)
{
    $article = Article::fine($id);

    //check if article exists to avoid errors
    if ( $article ) {
        return Datatables::of(Comment::where('article_id', $article->id))->make(true);
    }

    return "no article with id" . $id;
}
```

This was just an illustration. But it seems you need to understand first how Eloquent works. Watch this free Laracast https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/7

For routes, you can define the route like this:

```
Route::get('comments/{article_id}', 'ArticleController@commentsForOneArticle');
```

And call it in Ajax like

```
$.ajax({url: "/comments/1", 
    success: function(result){
        //do stuff here
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```

All this is just a guide and not THE solution.

**Edit**

To take data with the user in one go

```
$article = Article::with('user')->find($id);
//will include all the fields from user and article
```

**Comments & author**
To get the name of the comment author, you need to define the relationship in comment model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Then get like this

```
if ( $article ) {
    return Datatables::of(Comment::with('users')->where('article_id', $article->id))->make(true);
}
```

Comment: great now how about Route i think i should Pass the variable

Comment: and how i can Pass the variable through  "ajax": '{{route(' route here')}}',

Comment: First thing first, If any answer helps you on Stackoverflow, you need to upvote it or mark it as the answer. Now for your other question, you need to learn basic routing: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters then if you are stuck, I can assist but try first. I dont forget to upvote my and mark ny answer. Thanks.

Comment: this is the first use for StackOverflow , to be honest i don't know rolls here so thank you for solution  and thank you for give me idea about Stackoverflow

Comment: You are welcome. I added a little extra for you. Not as a solution, but as a guide for your ajax request.

Comment: if i need add more advanced  to same example like ` $article = Article::with('User')->select('articles.*');` and in view `{ data: 'user.name' } '
`

Comment: in the same example i want show user name  { data: 'user.name' }  can i use somthing like   ->with()

Comment: hi EddyTheDove  i need  the name of user that  how write the comment not Article , I think i can use editColumn but i don't know how .